# Run html inside js function on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert

I want to add form inside this swal alert with style with simple form like this [form example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-contact-form)

```
<div id="centerprize" style="display: ;">
    <a href='#' class="modal-btnprize">Win Prize</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".modal-btnprize").click(function() {
        var list='<div class="form-group">'+'<label for="InputName">YourName</label>'+
        '<div class="input-group">'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>'+
        '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span></div>'+
        '</div>'
        swal({
            title: "Eligibility Criteria",
            allowOutsideClick:true,
            text: list,
            html:true,
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: actually, you omitted the semicolon after your list variable declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'list' (contains html elements) variable should be in html and not in text as shown on my snippet. Also, you're using Bootstrap's input class so I think you might also add bootstrap and font-awesome if you want to achieve this 
[form](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-contact-form)

You can also look in [swal](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) for updates.

```js
$(".modal-btnprize").click(function() {
        var list='<div class="form-group">'+'<label for="InputName">YourName</label>'+
        '<div class="input-group">'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>'+
        '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span></div>'+
        '</div>'
        
        swal({
            title: "Eligibility Criteria",
            allowOutsideClick:true,
            text: 'Not html here',
            html: list,
        });   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.4/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.4/sweetalert2.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="centerprize" style="display: ;">
    <a href='#' class="modal-btnprize">Win Prize</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for the solution bro can you explain me the list part where i went wrong

Comment: `swal({
            title: "Eligibility Criteria",
            allowOutsideClick:true,
            text: 'Not html here',
            html: list,
        });   `   As you seen here, the **list** is put into `html` andnot in `text`, I think `text` only support text formats such as <b></b> and not `html` elements like `input type`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you don't see your html right. This is because sweetalert has a CSS class called `.sweet-alert input`. This has the attribute display:none;, which only disappears when you change the swal type. But in your case just define a new class with `display:block` or `inline-block`.

NOTE: This is for the original sweetalert by the way, not Sweetalert2.

PS: Next time it would be helpful if you let us know what exactly isn't working.